# Bootcamp on Mac Pro 5.1 — Boot keyboard shortcuts no longer working

Tags: windows, bootcamp, startup, mac-pro

I've installed Bootcamp running Windows 10 on my 2012 5.1 Mac Pro with Mojave. I've also upgraded my GPU to an RX580 from MacVidCards with the Apple EFI mod.

Everything went well for a few months until about a week ago when using Windows, I restarted and tried using the option key method to access the boot screen and select my Mac drive. It simply ignored the key press and loaded Windows instead. In fact, I've tried many of the keyboard shortcuts for different boot options (CMD+R, CMD+Option+P+R, etc.) to no avail. I've made sure to press the buttons at the right time and all that mess.

I've spent the better part of last week searching for any sort of answers, but nothing seemed to fit my situation. Hopefully it's something simple and sweet!

Any ideas?

Comment: Isn't Cmnd+Option+P+R to reset the Pram and not a drive select? If you have a firmware password then it will start macos Recovery. See https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT201255

Comment: 1st: try another keyboard, most especially if the one you're using isn't a real Apple aluminium. 2nd: though it may not help, the one thing you can do on a Pro without a working keyboard is reset the SMC. Power down, unplug from the mains for 15 seconds. Plug back in, wait 5 seconds, power on. The SMC does contain *some* keyboard parameters, but I'm not sure quite what on a 5,1.

Comment: Hey all, thanks for the replies! I have tested my Apple USB keyboard with another computer and it worked (but I'm getting another one just to be double-sure). To be clear, no key combination shortcut works during boot up. I've tried all that I could find and it simply boots directly into Windows every time. I did try resetting the SMC using the above method, but nothing changed unfortunately.

Comment: It works! I was able to test a new keyboard and that was the issue. Thanks again for your help!